# What is the proper procedure for upgrading a nvidia card?

Tags: drivers, upgrade, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I'm using Linux Mint. I already know how to do it in Windows but I'd like to know how to upgrade. I'm going to be changing from a GT 610 to a GTX 950. Is there anything I need to change like drivers?

Comment: Are you using mint managed drivers for your current card, or have you manually installed the Nvidia drivers from Nvidia directly?

Comment: Installed drivers from mint because I couldn't figure out how to do it from nvidia.com but it works non the less

Comment: If you are using the mint drivers you should be able to change the card, I believe mint is smart enough to do the leg work for you

Comment: So system shutdown, then switch cards, then turn on? Without changing drivers.

Comment: Would dropping to the nouveau driver work before moving cards?

Comment: Basicly, you're good to go, nothing to do (and I wonder why you would need to do anything in Windows too). Just use the driver manager to check you're using the most recent driver in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll finish this as an answer. Mint should be able to detect the change and fix any problems. So:

1. Shutdown
2. Replace card
3. Boot

That being said, as a safety precaution, since things do go wrong sometimes, download the Nvidia drivers from their website. Before making the switch.

If something goes wrong you will boot into run level 3 (cmd line) just issue :

```
chmod +x <driver file name >
```

Then run it with :

. /NVIDIA-SOME-FILE-NAME

And follow the prompt. It will ask you at the end of you want it to configure your xorg configuration, yes to that and then reboot when finished

Comment: How do I do the whole nvidia thing? Adding the driver with chmod

Comment: Just download it from Nvidia, and chmod +x whatever the file name is to make it executable, then to run it you just precede the file name with ./ (dot slash) it will run automatically from there minus a few menu options that you more or less just say yes to

Comment: Ok downloading now

Comment: I'll get back to you after I run it.

Comment: Only run it after you replace the card, if mint doesn't auto detect the driver.

Comment: Don't use the driver from the nvidia website, use the driver manager from mint, at least, you'll get updates from the update manager.